# Simplify $\frac{100(1-\frac pn)\sqrt[3]{\frac np}}{\sum_{0<a\le k}100(1-\frac ak)\sqrt[3]{\frac ka}}\sum_{0<b\le n}100(1-\frac bn)\sqrt[3]{\frac nb}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I use a formula in order to calculate player's points according to its rank and the total number of players :

$$100.(1-\frac{p}{n}).\sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{p}}$$

Where :

- *p* is the rank
- *n* is the total number of players

Now, I want to calculate all awarded points, so I do the sum :
$$\sum_{0<a\le{n}}100.(1-\frac{a}{n}).\sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{a}}$$

Where :

- *a* is the rank between 1 and *n* (total number of players)

Now, I want to put a limit between players who will be rewarded and others (for example, with a total of 50 players, I want only the half rewarded, so 25, like poker tournaments). But I still want to award full points.

So, I thought about this solution :
$$\frac{PlayerPoints}{TotalPointsRewarded}.TotalPoints$$

It is the percentage of points awarded to the player out of the total points awarded to rewarded players, which is then applied to the total points :

- *PlayersPoints* --> Points of a specific player (using the first formula)

  - *n* the total number of players
  - *p* the rank of player (> 0 && <= n)
- *TotalPointsRewarded* --> Sum of points of awarded players (using the second formula)

  - *n* the total number of players rewarded (<= total number of players)
  - *a* is the rank between *1* and *n*
- *TotalPoints* --> Sum of points of all players (using the second formula)

  - *n* the total number of players
  - *a* is the rank between *1* and *n*

So the final equation looks like this :
$$\frac{100.(1-\frac{p}{n}).\sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{p}}}{\sum_{0<a\le{k}}100.(1-\frac{a}{k}).\sqrt[3]{\frac{k}{a}}}.\sum_{0<b\le{n}}100.(1-\frac{b}{n}).\sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{b}}$$

Where :

- *a* is the rank between 1 and *k*
- *b* is the rank between 1 and *n*
- *k* is the number of players rewarded (> 0 && >= *p* && <= *n*)
- *n* is the total number of players
- *p* is the rank of the player (> 0 && <= *k*)

Do you know if it could be simplified ? My objective is to calculate this in Excel.